# derivative with respect to a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Had check some previous questions regarding the derivatives of diagonal matrices, but haven't found a form like this.

If $K=Wdiag(s)W^T$, in which $W$ is an m-by-n matrix, and $diag(s)$ represents an n-by-n diagonal matrix of which diagonal is represented by the vector $s$. I'm interested in the derivative of the log-determinant of K, ($\frac{\partial{ln}|K|}{\partial{s}}$), but I get stuck at solving this part: $\frac{\partial{K}}{\partial{s}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K=W \operatorname{diag}(s) W^T$. According to the CAS http://www.matrixcalculus.org/:

> $$   \frac{\partial }{\partial s}\log(\det(K)) =   \operatorname{diag}(W^T K^{-1} W)  $$

So lets prove that by hand as well. By the chain rule and [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) we have

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \log(\det(K))}{\partial s} 
&= \frac{\partial \log(\det(K))}{\partial \det (K)}\circ \frac{\partial\det(K)}{\partial K}\circ \frac{\partial K}{\partial s} \\
&= \frac{1}{\det (K)}\cdot \operatorname{tr}\Big(\operatorname{adj}(K)\frac{\partial K}{\partial s}\Big) 
= \operatorname{tr}\Big(K^{-1}\frac{\partial K}{\partial s}\Big) \\
\end{aligned}$$

Here, we need to be careful: $\frac{\partial K}{\partial s}$ is a $m\times m\times n$ tensor, and the trace collapses the first two dimensions. As Karthik Kannan showed $\frac{\partial K}{\partial s_j}=w_jw_j^T$, where $w_j$ is the $j$-th column vector of $W$. Hence

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{tr}\Big(K^{-1}\frac{\partial K}{\partial s}\Big) 
&=\operatorname{tr}\Big(K^{-1}\frac{\partial K}{\partial s_j}\Big)_j
=\operatorname{tr}\Big(K^{-1}w_j w_j^T\Big)_j \\
&=\operatorname{tr}\Big(w^T_j K^{-1}w_j\Big)_j
= \Big(w^T_j K^{-1}w_j\Big)_j
= \operatorname{diag}(W^T K^{-1} W)
\end{aligned}  $$

Answer (score 3):

We have, with $S = \operatorname{Diag}(s)$:

$$
\begin{align}
K &= W S W^T\\
dK &= W dS W^T
\end{align}
$$

Finding the differential and gradient of your expression, knowing that $K$ is symmetric:

$$
\eqalign{
f &= \log \det(K)    \\
  &= \operatorname{tr}(\log(K))   \\
  df &= K^{-T} : dK \\
  &= K^{-1} :  W dS W^T\\
  &= W^T K^{-1} W : dS\\
  &= \operatorname{diag}(W^T K^{-1} W) : ds
}
$$

Thus we can identify:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} = \operatorname{diag}(W^T K^{-1} W)
\end{equation}

---

The colon used here denotes the Frobenius inner product:

$$ A:B = \operatorname{tr}(A^TB)$$

with the following properties derived from the underlying trace function

$$\eqalign{A:BC &= B^TA:C\cr &= AC^T:B\cr &= A^T:(BC)^T\cr &= BC:A \cr } $$

Comment: $W$ is $m\times n$, what is $W^{-T}$ supposed to be?

Comment: @Hyperplane, you are right, I thought $W$ was $n \times n$.  Corrected now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We have $(\text{diag}(s))_{pq} = s_{p}\delta_{pq}$. So,
$$\dfrac{\partial K_{ij}}{\partial s_{k}} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial s_{k}}\sum_{p,q}W_{ip}(\text{diag}(s))_{pq}W_{jq} = \sum_{p,q}W_{ip}\delta_{pk}\delta_{pq}W_{jq} = \sum_{p}W_{ip}\delta_{pk}W_{jp} = W_{ik}W_{jk}$$